# Physical interpretations of covariance and correlation in Statistics

Tags: correlation-functions, statistics, covariance

(I was directed to this site from Mathematics SE!)

From what I know, theoretically, **covariance** is a measure of *the degree to which two variables change together.* A positive covariance indicates that the variables *increase or decrease together,* while a negative covariance indicates that *one variable increases as the other decreases.* **Correlation**, on the other hand, is a standardized version of covariance that measures the *strength* and *direction* of a linear relationship between two random variables. Correlation ranges from $-1$ to $1$, where $-1$ indicates a perfect negative linear relationship, $0$ indicates no linear relationship, and $1$ indicates a perfect positive linear relationship.

More generally, *correlation does not necessarily imply causation.* Correlation simply indicates that there is a relationship between two variables, but it does not specify the nature of the relationship. It is possible for two variables to be correlated without one causing the other.

(I read the following example somewhere, but unfortunately, I don't remember where exactly!) For example, ice cream sales and the number of drowning deaths might be positively correlated because both increase during the summer months. However, this does not mean that ice cream causes drowning deaths. In this case, a third variable, summer, is the cause of both ice cream sales and drowning deaths.

**Question:** Let's say under some circumstances the correlation between *age* and *income* turns out to be $0.75.$ But, as we know, these two ordinal variables need not necessarily increase or decrease together. However, according to me, the value of $0.75$ is statistically significant enough to indicate that the variables have a strong correlation! In other words, does this (relatively high) value have no impact on the relationship, if any, between age and income?

As mentioned above, I find "correlation" alone to be misleading to some extent. Moreover, in data science, there is this concept of *correlation measure,* which is used in clustering (please correct me if I'm wrong!). Since correlation $\nRightarrow$ causation, is it actually possible to group any two objects together based only on the value of the correlation between the two?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: It should be really in the statistics community - CrossValidated. Sorry.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs to Cross validated (statistics) community.